# nfR52840 dongle as RCP - fails with RadioSpinelNoResponse

Tags: rcp, dongle, openthread

this seems pretty much like https://github.com/openthread/ot-nrf528xx/issues/172
same thing here.but the github issue seems abandoned. i am totly lost on this one.
it is perfectly possible to issue commands via  "screen /dev/ttyACM0 115200", however connecting otbr-agent consistently fails.

this is how i build the firmware:

```
+ cmake -GNinja -DOT_COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR=ON -DNRF_PLATFORM=nrf52840 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=MinSizeRel -DOT_PLATFORM=external -DOT_SLAAC=ON -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=src/nrf52840/arm-none-eabi.cmake -DOT_USB=ON -DOT_EXTERNAL_MBEDTLS=nordicsemi-mbedtls -DOT_THREAD_VERSION=1.2 -DOT_BOOTLOADER=USB /home/markus/src/openthread/ot-nrf528xx
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.1
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- OpenThread Source Directory: /home/markus/src/openthread/ot-nrf528xx/openthread
-- OpenThread CMake build type: MinSizeRel
-- Package Name: OPENTHREAD
-- Setting default package version: thread-reference-20200818-1367-g02d29cd5e
-- Package Version: thread-reference-20200818-1367-g02d29cd5e
```

i am using /dev/ttyACM0:

```
markus@R2D2:~/src/openthread/ot-nrf528xx$ ls -l /dev/ttyACM0 
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 166, 0 Nov 25 18:00 /dev/ttyACM0
```

this is how i call the agent:

```
    otbr-agent -I wpan0 -B wlp2s0 spinel+hdlc+uart:///dev/ttyACM0?uart-baudrate=9600 trel://wlp2s0 -v
    otbr-agent[69707]: [INFO]-UTILS---: Running 0.3.0-7d61390
    otbr-agent[69707]: [INFO]-UTILS---: Thread version: 1.2.0
    otbr-agent[69707]: [INFO]-UTILS---: Thread interface: wpan0
    otbr-agent[69707]: [INFO]-UTILS---: Backbone interface: wlp2s0
    otbr-agent[69707]: [INFO]-UTILS---: Radio URL: spinel+hdlc+uart:///dev/ttyACM0?uart-baudrate=9600
    otbr-agent[69707]: [INFO]-UTILS---: Radio URL: trel://wlp2s0
    otbr-agent[69707]: 50d.00:10:14.071 [WARN]-PLAT----: Error processing notification: Parse
    otbr-agent[69707]: 50d.00:10:16.061 [CRIT]-PLAT----: HandleRcpTimeout() at /home/markus/src/openthread/ot-br-posix/third_party/openthread/repo/src/lib/spinel/radio_spinel_impl.hpp:2218: RadioSpinelNoResponse
```

Comment: Did you notice you are starting otbr with uart-baudrate 9600. you are capable of issueing commands to CLI at 115200 baud using screen.

Answer (score 1):

Fixes found on net are wrong:
don't flash the `cli`,

flash `ot-rcp` instead!

```
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O ihex build/bin/ot-cli-ftd ot-cli-ftd.hex needs to be
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O ihex build/bin/ot-rcp ot-rcp.hex
```

Comment: ot-cli for a command line interface,
ot-rcp is used for OTBR,
ot-ncp is used for wpantund